# In Space Quest 4, what files are on your desktop at the end of the game?

Tags: space-quest-4

In Space Quest 4, what files are on your desktop at the end of the game? A friend was telling me about the game and said that there were four files. He said there was the recycle bin, "two random files", and Space Quest. What are the random files?

Comment: Please retag as space-quest if you have the rep to create a tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Just to clarify: This isn't your *actual* computer desktop, it's a scene in the actual game.)

The two random files are Leisure Suit Larry 4, and Kings Quest XLIII.

> According to the plot, Leisure Suit Larry 4 was stolen and "infected" with Vohaul. Of course, in reality, the game was simply never made.

Clip from a playthrough below, showing the scene in question:

Comment: Excellent, thanks. The question is answered by the video. The files are just garbled icons.